# Stack push operation implementation not working

Tags: c++, pointers, stack, implementation

I'm writing my own stack to practice the language and practice pointers. I am using a linked list to represent the stack rather than an array. The push operation just assigns the top nodes value to every node and I can't figure out why, I tried writing an assignment operator but it didn't do anything.

```
template <class T>
void stack<T>::push(T data) {

//Operation to preform if the stack is empty.
//Root element is popped off last (First in, Last out)
if ( empty() ) {
root_node = new node;
root_node->node_data = data;
root_node->next = nullptr;
elements++;
 }

//Operation to preform if stack is not empty.
//Elements inserted into stack with dynamic allocation.
else  {
node *new_node = new node; 


/* PROBLEM AREA */

new_node = root_node; 
root_node->next = new_node;                  
root_node->node_data = data;                 

elements++;
 }
```

Here is the node structure

```
struct node {     //Definition of node structure with constructor and destructor

T node_data;
node *next;

//default ctor
node() { next = nullptr;  }

//default dtor
~node() { delete root_node; }

node operator=(const node &rhs) {
        if ( this != &rhs) {
        this->next = rhs->next;
        this->node_data = rhs->node_data;
        }
    return *this;
 }
};
```

Output when pushing 10, 20, 40 , 30 and popping them off and calling top()

```
Top element 30

Current Top Element: 30  size of stack 3
Current Top Element: 30  size of stack 2
Current Top Element: 30  size of stack 1
```

Comment: _'This is the output I get If ...'_ Uhhhm what? I can't spot any output sample? (formatting code properly avoiding any scroll bars, also might help to improve readability!!)

Comment: `new_node = root_node;` the `new node` you just allocated is now lost forever.

Comment: Your `root_node` never changes but `root_node->node_data = data;` keeps changing data

Comment: @user657267 Why is the new node lost? Doesn't the new node just assume the members of the root node? e.g. the new node assumes a data value of 20 and points to null.

Comment: @Revoo You assign a new node to `new_node`, and in the very next line you assign `root_node` to `new_node`, nothing else points to the new node and so it can no longer be retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overloaded `operator=` is wrong. You have:

```
node operator=(const node &rhs) {
```

so it returns a copy by value.  You didn't define a copy-constructor so this will be a "shallow copy" which will lead to problems.

The usual way to define `operator=` is

```
node& operator=(const node &rhs) {
```

However, the logic inside this function doesn't make sense either:

```
    if ( this != &rhs) {
    this->next = rhs->next;
    this->node_data = rhs->node_data;
    }
```

Now you will have 2 nodes that both point to the same `next`. So you no longer have a list, you have some sort of upside-down tree going on.

---

You should either implement or `delete`/`private` your copy-constructor, to eliminate the possibility that unexpected shallow copies are happening.

---

Another big issue is:

```
node *new_node = new node; 
new_node = root_node;
```

You make a `new node` but then you immediately leak that memory and make `new_node` point to `root_node` instead. Based on your description I suspect you meant:

```
*new_node = *root_node;
```

which means `new_node->operator=(*root_node);` calling your `operator=` function.

---

To summarize, the whole thing is such a mess than you're probably better redoing it from scratch. I'd recommend separating your code into two parts:

- The linked list
- The stack logic

Write the linked list on its own and check that it works.  (This should be a class)

Once that's done, then you can do your stack implementation on top of the linked list.

Comment: Great answer! I overlooked the fact I am working with pointers here and not node objects. I presume that the statement *new_node = *root_node de-references the pointers and assigns the node values to one another?

Comment: Yes that's what it does. If you assign pointers it means to make one pointer point to what the other was pointing to; but if you assign non-pointer objects then it calls the target's `operator=`.

Answer (score 0):

You do the assignments in the else part (where your problem is) in the wrong order. The second statement immediately clobbered the newly allocated node. What you should have is:

```
node *new_node = new node;
new_node->node_data = data;
new_node->next = root_node->next;
root_node = new_node;
elements++;
```

Comment: The segfault comes from the overloaded assignment operator (as noted in @matt-mcnabb's answer.